# Which Win32 user-mode handles can be shared among processes?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, kernel, handles

I've been trying to better understand WinAPIs and the underlying Windows kernel. From what I see so far, `HWND` (window) handles can be shared among processes.

But what about other handles, can they be shared among processes?

`HMODULE`, `HINSTANCE`, [`ATOM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633587(v=vs.85).aspx)?

As well as window and drawing components:

`HMENU`, `HDC`, `HICON`, `HCURSOR`, `HBRUSH`, etc.?

And lastly, if all of the above cannot be shared, are there any user-mode handles that can be?

EDIT: Clarification. By *sharing*, I meant taking the handle's numerical value from one process and using it in another process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HMODULE` and `HINSTANCE` is the same thing on 32 and 64-bit Windows. It is the base address of a module and cannot really be shared across processes (except the addresses of ntdll and kernel32 if the other process has the same bitness).

`ATOM`s come in per-process and global forms and the global form can be shared by processes on the same [windowstation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687096(v=vs.85).aspx).

The GDI drawing handles cannot be shared (except for maybe `GetStockObject`?).

> Under Windows NT, GDI objects are stored in the client part of the Win32 subsystem's GDI module. That means that [any GDI object is valid only in the context of the application that created it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810501.aspx).

USER32 handles (HWND, HMENU, HICON, HCURSOR) can be shared.

`DuplicateHandle` accepts desktop and windowstation handles...

Comment: Windows 95/98/ME might be different, I don't remember the details anymore. Parts of the kernel is 16-bit and there is no security so you might be able to play games. HMODLUEs of kernel32, user32, gdi32 and more can all be shared because they load at a special high address. This might not apply to ntdll because it is not a base dll on these systems.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Two quick follow ups. 1) What would be the API that uses a `global` form of an `ATOM` handle? and 2) By shared, I meant taking a numeric value of a handle from one process and using it in another, just like `HWND`. If such, can `HMENU`, `HICON`, `HCURSOR` be really shared? PS. Sorry, can't upvote. Not enough juice.

Comment: @MikeF, [USER object handles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725486) are public within a Session and usable if you have read-write access to open the associated Desktop. Normally the global [atom table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649053) is in the WindowStation, such as the only interactive WindowStation in a Session, "WinSta0". Note that a Process may be limited to just USER objects and atoms of processes in the same Job if it has [`JOBOBJECT_BASIC_UI_RESTRICTIONS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684152).

Comment: @eryksun: Thanks for the info. I was reading about those `ATOM`s and it sounds like something very old. Something that came out from Windows 1.x. I'm still trying to understand why they might've needed such a convoluted construct. (It's a rhetorical question.) As for other USER object handles, I didn't know that you can plainly copy the handle value and use it in another process if you have the access rights. Good info!

Comment: Global `ATOM`s are used by DDE to transfer strings from one process to another.

Comment: @MikeF, you'll see DDE/OLE related atoms pinned at the start of the global atom table, starting with 0xC001 (StdExit). The kernel has some system calls related to this table -- `NtQueryInformationAtom` (atom and table info), `NtAddAtom`, `NtDeleteAtom`, `NtFindAtom`. These calls first get the global atom table from the current thread's WindowStation (or Job) and call the corresponding runtime library functions `RtlQueryAtomInAtomTable`, `RtlQueryAtomsInAtomTable` (table info, kernel only), `RtlAddAtomToAtomTable`, `RtlDeleteAtomFromAtomTable`, and `RtlLookupAtomInAtomTable`.

Comment: @MikeF, USER also makes extensive use of atoms, but it has its own table separate from the WindowStation table. You can inspect this table using a kernel debugger. Its address is stored in `win32kbase!UserAtomTableHandle`, or just in win32k in older versions. The first string entry, 0xC001, is "USER".

Comment: @eryksun: Hey, good idea & thanks for the info. I'll give good ol' WinDbg a try. I guess that was the way to implement IPC back then. It's too bad that the `ATOM` table strings cannot be longer than 255 `wchar_t`'s, (or maybe even 255 bytes if documentation doesn't have a bug.) You can't even reliably put a file path into it.